# The manual Dempster–Shafer theory in GIS?

Tags: gis-principle

I am looking for the manual Dempster–Shafer theory.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I had not heard of this but was able to find this web page by using Google to search for "manual Dempster–Shafer theory":

> [What Is Dempster-Shafer Theory And Can It Fill The Void Left By Bayesian Models?](https://www.analyticsindiamag.com/dempster-shafer-theory-the-whats-and-the-hows/)
>
> Introduced by Arthur P Dempster and developed by Glenn Shafer, the
>   Dempster-Shafer theory was designed to mathematically model and
>   validate the uncertainty involved in statistical inferences. This
>   theory allows one to combine evidence from different sources and
>   arrive at a degree of belief, which is mathematically defined by
>   belief functions (Bel).